# How can i hide product slider extension from Contact us, Terms and conditions, and 404 not found page?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have installed a third party product slider extension in my Magento 1.9. I have enabled it only in the homepage. As in the backend (CMS->pages) the pages contact us, terms and conditions and 404 not found page comes as the sub of the homepage. Since the product slider is showing in all those pages. How can i remove slider from all other pages and retain it in the homepage only?
Thanks in advance

Comment: can you share screenshot or url? Which extension are you using?

Answer (score 0):

In layout update tab of CMS page you can remove it for those particular CMS pages.

Add following one:

```
<reference name="content">
   <remove name="YOUR_SLIDER_BLOCK_NAME"/>
</reference>
```